# Parallel execution on multiple directories

Tags: makefile

I would like to create multiple directories with some files with one makefile.

I've a directory structure like this:

```
conf_a/conf.json
conf_b/conf.json
main.py
Makefile
requirements.txt
```

And would like to type `make conf_a` and having a new directory like this:

```
build/conf_a/conf.json
build/conf_a/main.py
build/conf_a/requirements.txt
conf_a/conf.json
conf_b/conf.json
main.py
Makefile
requirements.txt
```

Or something like `make conf_b` and having a new directory like this:

```
build/conf_b/conf.json
build/conf_b/main.py
build/conf_b/requirements.txt
conf_a/conf.json
conf_b/conf.json
main.py
Makefile
requirements.txt
```

So I've made a Makefile like this:

```
# Disable built-in rules and variables
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-variables
.ONESHELL:
.SHELLFLAGS: -ec
.SILENT:

BUILD_DIR := $(CURDIR)/build
CONF_FILE := conf.json
FILES_TO_COPY := requirements.txt main.py

FUNCTION_DIRS := $(shell ls */$(CONF_FILE) | xargs -n 1 -I {} dirname {})
HIDDEN_FUNCTION_DIRS := $(shell ls .*/$(CONF_FILE) 2> /dev/null | xargs -n 1 -I {} dirname {})


clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)

all: clean $(FUNCTION_DIRS) deploy

$(FUNCTION_DIRS) $(HIDDEN_FUNCTION_DIRS):
    tmp=$@
    FUNCTION_DIR=$${tmp%/}
    export FUNCTION=$${FUNCTION_DIR#.}
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)/$$FUNCTION
    cp -f $(FILES_TO_COPY) $$FUNCTION_DIR/$(CONF_FILE) $(BUILD_DIR)/$$FUNCTION/

test:
    for FUNCTION in $(shell ls $(BUILD_DIR))
    do
        echo "Testing $$FUNCTION"
    done

deploy:
    for FUNCTION in $(shell ls $(BUILD_DIR))
    do
        echo "Deploying $$FUNCTION"
    done
```

Well, it works...

So if I want to test a conf I do: `make conf_a test`.
If I want to deploy: `make conf_b deploy`

It work quiet well but `test` or `deploy` target are sequential (because the for loop) and they could have been parallel.

My problem is that I'se too much configuration directories and because the deploy is slow parallel could have been a lot better.

But I do not know how to structure a `Makefile` to make it this way.

Any idea ?

---

Truth be told, the task `deploy` deploy a GCP cloud function, and the `test` just run the function locally

Comment: "*It work quiet well*" -- it doesn't look like it would work at all.  Each line in a rule's recipe is interpreted as a separate command, and is run in its own shell.  Your `test` and `deploy` targets should therefore fail loudly and obviously.  Your `$(FUNCTION_DIRS)` target should misbehave more subtly.

Comment: You are true, except in this case I’ve set the variable ONESHELL that spaw one shell by target and not by line. So it work well (and I use it already).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the easiest way to structure a makefile to facilitate parallel operations is to define separate targets that can be processed in parallel.  Then you can use `make`'s `-j` option to request that *it* take care of the parallelization across (up to) a specific maximum number of parallel tasks.

For example:

```
deploy: deploy_a deploy_b

deploy_a: conf_a
    echo deploying conf_a

deploy_b: conf_b
    echo deploying conf_b
```

Then you can `make -j2 deploy` and (probably) the `deploy_a` and `deploy_b` rules will be processed in parallel.  But note that that might not help much.  Even though you have separate processes for the two deployments, if you're deploying both to the same local disk then they won't be able to both use write to different files on the disk at the same time.  As a result, you'll probably not see a significantly better time to completion, and it might even be worse.

Note, too, that the above example eschews dynamically determining the available component directories.  Such dynamism is atypical of makefiles, and IMO it rarely provides a net benefit.  Nevertheless, GNU `make` (on which specific implementation you are already relying) does offer mechanisms by which you could generate the needed per-directory deployment rules dynamically.

Comment: First: the deploy do not deploy locally but in the cloud (a cloud function btw).
Second: the problem with this organisation is that I can deploy only one function (let's say only `conf_a`)
I've tried something with a key word (like `make deploy FUNCTION=conf_a`) but it's not really nice too....

Comment: What makes you say you can deploy only one function?  Running `make deploy` will deploy both.  Or did you mean your *can't* deploy only one?  But of course you can -- there is a separate target for each one, so you can simply use the appropriate target.  For example, `make deploy_a` to deploy just function a.

Comment: Sorry My bad.
I've more thant 50 functions definitions so I can't duplicate.
And I really need something for testing and something for deploying.

Here I can't have both.

Comment: Of course you can use this approach.  Having 50 separate functions to deal with does not preclude that.  If you don't want to manage it *manually*, then you can write a code generator to generate part or all of the makefile, or, as I said, GNU `make` has facilities (`$(eval)`) by which you could generate the wanted rules dynamically.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna take a look to this ! (I've miss that in the doc).